# Two questions in calculus

Tags: calculus, limits

Please help me with the following questions:

1) $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }\left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}%
+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}}{2\sqrt[3]{n^{2}}}\right)$?

2) Let $f$ be a differentiable function on $[1,\,\infty )$ and $f(1)=1$.

If $f^{\prime}(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^{2}+f(x)^{2}}$, then why $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow
+\infty }f(x)$ is finite.

Comment: own thoughts???

Comment: What work have you done so far on this problem?

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints.

i) Is it the limit of a Riemann sum?

ii) Show that $f$ is increasing (easy) and bounded:
$$f(x)-1=f(x)-f(1)=\int_1^x f'(t) dt=\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t^{2}+f^2(t)}
\\\leq \int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t^{2}+1}=\arctan(x)-\arctan(1).$$

Comment: Why $f$ is bounded?

Comment: @M. T See my edited answer and fill the details.

Comment: :Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

With 1) you can also use the theorem of Cesaro-Stolz. Set $A_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}
+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$, $B_n=2\sqrt[3]{n^{2}}$, then as
$$
\frac{A_n-A_{n-1}}{B_n-B_{n-1}}=\frac{n^{-1/3}}{2n^{2/3}-2(n-1)^{2/3}}=\frac1{n(1-(1-\frac1n)^{2/3})}
\\
=\frac1{n(1-1+\frac23\frac1n-\frac29\frac1{n^2}+O(\frac1{n^3}))}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac32
$$

converges, so does $\frac{A_n}{B_n}$ towards the same limit.